# HTML's "<img align=top>" in CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

How do I emulate

```
<img align='top' src='huge_image.jpg'>
<span>I start at the top right corner of the image!</span>
```

in CSS?

Maybe it's embarrassingly simple, but I really don't know.

Comment: never used `align='top'` - but doesn't `align='left'` do the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the container of your elements. The `vertical-align` CSS property doesn't exactly map to the `valign` attribute.  I recommend checking this link out for an explanation on how to achieve this with CSS. http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 8):

`float: left` will position it such that the img element will be to the left of the span, but if you are wanting to replicate `align="top"` because of the vertical alignment issue (span at bottom right vs. top right), then try `style="vertical-align: top;"`

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the [vertical-align](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) CSS property.

```
<img style="vertical-align: top;" alt="blah" src="blah.jpg" />
```

Ideally you wouldn't just slap it directly on the `<img>` tag, but instead use a CSS class.

Answer (score 2):

```
<style="text/css">

.top_aligned_image {vertical-align: top; /* or text-top, I can't remember for sure which works better */}

</style>

<img class="top_aligned_image" src='huge_image.jpg' /><span>I start at the top right corner of the image!</span>
```

Should do it.

Comment: Shouldn't that "top_aligned_image" rule have a "." in front?

Comment: ...umm...yes. Yes, it should. Thanks for that =) (edited and amended)

Answer (score 1):

edit:

I think you want the span to be inline with the image. So display:inline should do move the span to the right.

and

[vertical-align:text-top](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) should move the image to the top.